# Epsilon-Delta issues

Tags: limits, epsilon-delta

I still don't get it...

The statement

$\lim\limits_{x \to c} f(x)$ = *L*

is correct if for any postive number *ε* there is a *δ* such that if *x* is within *δ* units of *c*, then f(x) is within *ε* units of L... ok, I get that.

But then I tried to disprove

$\lim\limits_{x \to 2} \frac{x^2-4}{x-2}$ = *5*

And what I got was:

If *f(x)* is within 0.1 (*ε*) units of 5 (supposed *L*) it is either 4.9 or 5.1.

But if I plug in x as 2.9 or 3.1, the resulting *f(x)* is respectively 4.9 and 5.1; with the *δ* being 0.9 and 1.1 respectively...
If *ε* is smaller, then I can just get *δ* closer and closer to 1 to suffice that condition.

And so I still found a *δ* for every case...

I know this must all sound ridiculous, I'm just hoping to find where I'm thinking wrong.

Comment: I know that I've posted a question on the same topic yesterday and it is probably bad to do it again(?), but I think it is now a different perspective on the ε-δ, so I decided not to mix this one up with the last one... I'm sorry if this was bad

Comment: The limit is $x\to2$ so you want to consider $x$ near $2$, for example $x=1.9$ or $2.1$.  Taking $x=2.9$ and $3.1$ is going to have little relevance.

Comment: Also, for the limit, as $~x \to 2,~$ the specific value of $~x = 2,~$ is not to be considered.  This is why the definition of limit specifies $~\color{red}{0 < } ~|x - 2| < \delta.$

Comment: Thank you @David and user. Just so I know, what is the given definition missing?

Comment: Your numerical experiment hints at the fact that the limit as x approaches 3 is equal to 5, but this has no relevance in disproving the given statement because the pointwise limit of a function at 2 and 3 can be wildly different

Comment: @Nobody if you mean your definition in lines 4-5 of your question, nothing is missing... well to be super accurate, just one small thing, you should specify that there exists a *positive* $\delta$.

Comment: @David Let me see if I got it: x+δ has to be greater than 2 and x-δ has to be less than 2; since I defined 2 to be the limit which I'm analyzing? That's it, I think...?

Comment: Sounds fine.$\,\!$

Answer (score 1):

When you choose a value of $\delta$, you are requiring that *every* value of $x$ satisfying $0 < |x - x_0| < \delta$ results in a true implication for $|f(x) - L| < \varepsilon$.

In your example, when setting $\varepsilon = 0.1$, you suggest that we can choose $\delta = 0.9$ or $\delta = 1.1$. But that only makes things (sort of) correct at the boundary, which is not enough.

What values of $x$ satisfy $0 < |x - 2| < 0.9$? Not 2.9, not 3.1, but things like 2.1 and 2.5 and 1.4 - and for all of those values of $x$, you'll find that $f(x)$ is *more* than 0.1 away from 5.

Comment: Thank you. Is this somehow implied in the "classical" definition? { 0<|x-c|<0 and |f(x)−L|<ϵ }

Comment: Also, for the second paragraph: does that mean that δ also has to be arbitrarily small??? That must be what I am missing

Comment: This is absolutely what the classical definition is saying. It doesn't say "for some $x$ that satisfies $|x-c|<\delta$", it says "the fact that $x$ satisfies $|x-c|<\delta$ directly implies that $|f(x)-L|< \varepsilon$". And if the limit does exist, then you're going to find that shrinking $\varepsilon$ causes $\delta$ to get smaller too, except in cases like where $f$ is a constant.